# настройка удаленного сервера git

Tags: git, ssh

помогите с настройкой удаленного репозитория. По ключу норм соединяюсь к серверу под git а вот добавляю `git remote add origin git@site.ru:/home/git/git/project.git/`
ответ всегда

```
git push origin master
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

репозиторий создавал, ответ

```
Git repository in /home/git/git/project.git/
```

Генерировал 'ssh-keygen -t rsa`
Скопировал публичный ключ в autorized_keys
Права на репозиторий

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 git git 6 Jun 14 14:39 branches 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 git git 66 Jun 14 14:39 config 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 git git 73 Jun 14 14:39 description 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 git git 23 Jun 14 14:39 HEAD 
drwxrwxr-x 2 git git 332 Jun 14 14:39 hooks 
drwxrwxr-x 2 git git 21 Jun 14 14:39 info 
drwxrwxr-x 4 git git 30 Jun 14 14:39 objects 
drwxrwxr-x 4 git git 31 Jun 14 14:39 refs
```

с помощью Putty заходит , а так

```
ssh git@dev.*****.in.ua git@dev.*****.in.ua: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

Comment: 1, генерировали пару ключей программой ssh-keygen? 2. содержимое публичной части добавили пользователю git в файл ~/.ssh/authorized_keys? 3. секретную часть скопировали в каталог ~/.ssh своему локальному пользователю, от имени которого запусали программы git и ssh? 4. каталоги ~/.ssh и их содержмое в обоих случаях сделали доступными только владельцу? // форматированную информцию лучше добавлять в текст вопроса ([edit]), а лишние комментарии — удалять

Comment: Спасибо @aleksandrbarakin
Добавил в папку пользователя приватный ключ, в моем случае на Винде в свою папку. Заработпло

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/488423)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, я думаю это стоит оформить ответом

Comment: @0xdb, ответ который помог находится в комментарии к вопросу)

Comment: В общем то да))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

контрольный список вопросов, помогающий в диагностике проблемы доступа по протоколу *ssh* (именно этот протокол используется программой *git* в качестве транспортного, когда указан *url* хранилища вида `[пользователь@]имя_машины:путь/к/хранилищу`):

1. пару частей ключа — секретную и публичную — генерировали именно программой *ssh-keygen*?
2. содержимое публичной части добавили пользователю на отдалённой машине в файл `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`?
3. секретную часть скопировали в каталог `~/.ssh` своему локальному пользователю (от имени которого запускали программу *ssh*)?
4. каталоги `~/.ssh` и их содержмое в обоих случаях сделали доступными только владельцу?

Answer (score 0):

Добавление требует ключ. Иногда помогает, попробуйте добавить :

~/.ssh/config

```
host site.ru
 HostName site.ru
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_имя_ключа_вашего 
 User git
```

Comment: создал

host dev.******.in.ua
 HostName dev.******.in.ua
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
 User git

тоже самое. и еще запутался насчет ссылки,
git@site.ru:/home/git/git/project.git/ правильно?