# Какова причина неуспеха при подключении по ssh использованием ключа?

Tags: windows, ssh

Я пытаюсь автоматизировать доставку веб-приложения на сервер с использованием ssh.

На сервере, я создал отдельного Linux-пользователя, с выполнил от его имени команду ssh-keygen.
Затем я скопировал приватный ключ на свой компьютер и выполнил команду

```
ssh -i id_rsa -oBatchMode=yes -v github-deployer@<ip сервера>
```

И получил ошибку `Permission denied (publickey,password)`
При этом с конфигурацией сервера проблемы нет, от имени другого пользователя я спокойно подключаюсь, правда для него я генерировал ключ другим способом (сгенерировал на своём компьютере, и залил на сервер публичный ключ).

В файле `/var/log/auth.log` при попытке подключения наблюдаю всего одну строку:

```
Jun 27 12:28:07 seterator sshd[20567]: Connection reset by 46.242.39.189 port 64510 [preauth]
```

При запуске клиента ssh с ключом -v вывод следующий:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\m.prokazin/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to <ip сервера> [<ip сервера>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\m.prokazin\\Documents\\tmp\\key type 0  # <- это реальный путь к файлу приватного ключа
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\m.prokazin\\Documents\\tmp\\key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <ip сервера>:22 as 'github-deployer'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:g30wkiuNuaw6RZVbq0F0EsRyA1Gw8vbHfNruCF7iAS0
debug1: Host '<ip сервера>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\m.prokazin/.ssh/known_hosts:41
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:lvQ7LKb8X8XS/Gx5TmsldZ+aqwyAl6teujJB+dTBaYI C:\\Users\\m.prokazin\\Documents\\tmp\\key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
github-deployer@<ip сервера>: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Вся эта ситуация также воспроизводится на машине, с которой я по задумке должен подключаться с целью закинуть обновление.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Обычно ключи генераят на клиенте. А публичный ключ явно записывают в файл authorized_keys сервера. Если вы генерили файлы на сервере, то он их сам в authorized_keys не записывал ...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143693/178576

Comment: Файлы ключа в личной папке юзера на сервере лежат, я проверил это первым делом. Приватный ключ на стороне клиента я указываю явно при подключении.

Comment: @Mike, вы были правы. Я был невнимателен, публичный ключ действительно не записывается в `authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ключи генерируются на клиенте, а публичный ключ уже заливается на сервер
- проверьте, вписан ли в `authorized_keys` на сервере публичный ключ
- проверьте, закинули ли вы ключ на клиенте в `~/.ssh`
- проверьте права приватного ключа

Comment: Да, я понял. Моя ошибка была в том что при запуске ssh keygen публичный ключ записывался в файл `id_rsa.pub`, а не в `authorized_keys`.