# Проблема ssh key for user (RHEL 7)

Tags: ssh, ssh-key, ssh-agent

Не кидайтесь палками, изрыл весь инет и много чего попробовал))
Задача следующая: на нескольких серверах создается один и тот же локальный юзер и необходима авторизация на него с помощью ключа. С юзера на юзер
Что я пробовал:

1. Cоздал .ssh/ на юзере:
   mkdir /home/user4ik/.ssh/
2. Сгенерил ключ:
   ssh-key-gen
3. На другом сервере:
   mkdir /home/user4ik/.ssh/
4. Перекинул его юзеру другого сервера:
   ssh-copy-id user4ik@anotherserver
   Удостоверился, что появился файл authorized_keys в anotherserver
5. Дал права на все вложения  chmod 777 /home/user4ik/.ssh/ (на всякий случай) всем серверам
6. Авторизовался с головного сервера, согласно предписанию команды ssh-copy-id
7. На всех серверах правил конфиг /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
   PubkeyAuthentication yes
   PasswordAuthentication no

systemctl restart sshd

8. Проверка:
   Ни с одного из серверов не могу зайти с юзера на юзер Пишет Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
   По root заходит только с головного на другой
   Результат выполнения команды на обоих серверах ssh-add: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143693/178576 . вижу в вашем описании как минимум два ошибочных действия.

Answer (score 0):

Проделал ряд действий. В итоге если пароль в конфиге sshd_config оставляю, то "ходит и туда и туда". Если нет, то только с головного и то только от рута до рута.

С user4ik@головной

```
ls -la .ssh/

total 20

drwx------. 2 user4ik user4ik 80 Jul 27 18:06 .

drwx------. 6 user4ik user4ik 154 Jul 28 10:58 ..

-r--------. 1 user4ik user4ik 796 Jul 24 14:34 authorized_keys

-rw-r--r--. 1 user4ik user4ik 1679 Jul 27 14:02 id_rsa

-rw-r--r--. 1 user4ik user4ik 400 Jul 27 14:02 id_rsa.pub

-r--------. 1 user4ik user4ik 6300 Jul 27 17:17 known_hosts
```

Что-то накрутил на подчиненном и поэтому имею)):

```
user4ik@anotherserver

ls -la .ssh/

ls: cannot access .ssh/.: Permission denied

ls: cannot access .ssh/..: Permission denied

ls: cannot access .ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied

ls: cannot access .ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied

total 0

d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .

d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..

-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? authorized_keys

-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? known_hosts

root@anotherserver

ls -la ~/.ssh/

total 8

dr--------. 2 root root  48 Jul 23 17:33 .

dr-xr-x---. 6 root root 190 Jul 21 19:46 ..

-r--------. 1 root root 397 Jul 21 19:46 authorized_keys

-r--------. 1 root root 538 Jul 24 17:48 known_hosts
```

Вследствие чего не читается ключ. Выправляю через sudo - картина та же. При этом, если лезу в это папку из под root то там все выправляется, и выправлено:

```
ls -la user4ik/.ssh/*

-rw-r--r--. 1 user4ik user4ik 400 Jul 27 18:06 user4ik/.ssh/authorized_keys

-rw-r--r--. 1 user4ik user4ik 175 Jul 27 18:07 user4ik/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Думаю, может ключи переделать?

Comment: "Ходят все ко всем", если включаю авторизацию по паролю

Comment: В итоге, раздав все соответствующие права, user4ik@головной ходит норм без ввода пароля,

Comment: но со второго сервера Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)